# Laminar vs. turbulent boundary layer equations

Tags: thermodynamics, fluid-dynamics, dimensional-analysis, turbulence

The 2D boundary layer equations (continuity and momentum) are given by:

[image]

**Can these also be applied to turbulent boundary layers?** These simply come from Navier-Stokes and are simplified with scaling arguments, but I don't see where any laminar assumptions come in.

Furthermore, the velocity profile for laminar boundary layers is typically given by

$$ \frac{u}{U} = 2\frac{y}{\delta}-(\frac{y}{\delta})^2$$

where $\delta$ is the boundary layer thickness. This result arises from assuming a polynomial profile and then applying boundary conditions. However, I often see the turbulent boundary layer profile given by:

$$ \frac{u}{U} = (\frac{y}{\delta})^{1/7}$$

**Where does this come from?**

Comment: Turbulent flow displays small scale transience and associated turbulent stresses resulting from co-variance of velocity fluctuations.  Are you familiar with this?

Comment: @ChesterMiller I just read up on this a bit and I realize that now. So basically, we can use the same equations, they just have to be time-averaged. This still doesn't explain the $1/7$ power law for turbulent velocity profiles, though. I wonder if it's an experimental observation.